# install modules in playframework 2.0 - WANT TO include morphia in play 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

How to Install modules in Play Framework 2.0 ... play install doesnot seem to work.

it seems code has to be put in modules directory under frameworks. but none of the plugins i downloaded had modules directory ?

I want to get Play framework 2.0 work with Mongodb. preferably with

```
morphia.db.seeds="127.0.0.1:27017"
%prod.morphia.db.name=yabe
morphia.db.name=dev
morphia.id.type=Long
morphia.defaultWriteConcern=SAFE
morphia.collection.upload=fs
morphia.logger=false
```

Comment: I would want to have play framework + mongo + morphio work together

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed Play 1 and 2. Play install and `%prod` in configuration files are from play 1. Both play versions are incompatible to each other and so the modules.

There is a [listing for play 2 plugins](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules).
There is an [example application for morphia](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin/tree/master/samples/yabe) in play 2. To install the module you have to adjust your [Build.scala](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin/blob/master/samples/yabe/project/Build.scala).

Answer (score 0):

There's also the playMongoDemo is you want a Morphia version that works with 2.0: https://github.com/czihong/playMongoDemo

I have a pull request that updated the content to 2.1.4 here: https://github.com/subdigit/playMongoDemo

Though if/once it gets accepted, use the main repo.